# "Cannot fall through" Switch Error

Tags: c#, switch-statement

```
} else {
    int indexGenerator = numberGenerator.Next(1, 4);
    int answer1 = finalUserInput - theCorrectAnswer;
    switch (indexGenerator) {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("You are off by" + answer1);
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("So close. Maybe if you add or subtract " + answer1 + "?");
```

When I try to get the switch to work, an error message pops up saying Control Case Cannot Fall Through From Case1 to Another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `break;` at the end of each case in your switch statement.

```
switch (indexGenerator) {
  case 1:
      Console.WriteLine("You are off by" + answer1);
      break; 
  case 2:
      Console.WriteLine("So close. Maybe if you add or subtract " + answer1 + "?");
      break;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. :)

Comment: @Ken can you please mark this answer as correct (click the tick icon) so that the question is closed off as resolved, thanks

Comment: Sure. I need to wait four minutes though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you forgot to add `break;`'s to your code.  Your code should read as follows.

```
switch (indexGenerator){
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("You are off by" + answer1);
                break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("So close. Maybe if you add or subtract " + answer1 + "?");
                break;
}
```

The purpose of having the `break` is to basically tell your program that you are breaking away from that `case:` portion of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [`break`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/switch_statement_in_csharp.htm) at the end of the `case 1` block:

```
}
else
{
    int indexGenerator = numberGenerator.Next(1, 4);
    int answer1 = finalUserInput - theCorrectAnswer;
    switch (indexGenerator)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("You are off by" + answer1);
            break; // missing break
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("So close. Maybe if you add or subtract " + answer1 + "?");
            break; // missing break
```

Add one at the end of your `case 2` block as I've shown too.